# How do I center the nav bar, but keep even spacing on the left and right side?

Tags: html, css, center, nav

I'm having some trouble making my nav bar. I'd like it to look like I have it in the mockup here- https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc01i4ncy7nj66y/home.PNG

I'd like to center it without using margins, because certain elements don't appear to be responding to margin editing. Problem is that when I try to keep the spacing between the buttons (white separation lines), but also center the navbar, all sorts of weird formatting problems occur.

Here is my html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>AB Portfolio</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id = "FalseHeader">
   <header>
    <nav class="main">
     <ul>
      <li><a href"">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href"">About</a></li>
      <li><a href"">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
  </div>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="gallery">
  </div>    
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}


 body{
font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
color: #fff;
  }

 #FalseHeader{
width: 100%;
height:30px;
margin-top:100px;
background-color: #000;
 }  

 header {
width: 960px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
 }


 nav.main {
height: 30px;
margin-top:100px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: green;
 }

 /*nav.main ul{
height: 30px;
width: 500px;
display: inline;
background-color: red;
 }
 */
 nav.main ul li{
height: 30px;
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #000;
 }

 nav.main ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transtion: all 0.2s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 }

 nav.main ul li a:hover {
color: #A1A8B2;
 }


 #container{
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
 }

 #gallery{
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left top,
left bottom,
color-stop(0, #3D64B8),
color-stop(1, #1A4C8C)
 );
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #3D64B8 0%, #1A4C8C 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #3D64B8 0%, #1A4C8C 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #3D64B8 0%, #1A4C8C 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #3D64B8 0%, #1A4C8C 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3D64B8 0%, #1A4C8C 100%);

 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specify some alignment for your ul tag

```
ul{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
```

And if you don't want to use margin to leave the space between each buttons, you can use white border instead.